# Clash of Clans How are hero summoned unit level determined?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Are the summoned units of barbarian king and archer queen the same level as your own barbarians/archers? I always thought that depended on the level of your hero and not your own units but my level 15 barbarian is summoning level 1 barbs right now and I have level 1 barbs so I am suspecting this might be the case. I can't find info on this anywhere. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked, and it seems that the unit laboratory level is what affects the summoned unit level. Hero level only seems to affect the number of units summoned when the ability is activated.